# XSD restrict element type to ipadress type

Tags: xsd

I restrict a ipadress element type like ipadress:port.This is the code.

```
<xs:element name = "Ipadress">
 <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value = "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

but it does not work.Some ipadress such as

```
<Ipadress> 127.0.0.1:123 </Ipadress>
```

will be fail to validate.

Comment: you should spell it `ipaddress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape Dot(`.`) with the slash (`\`)

```
<xs:element name="Ipadress">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

**OR**

```
<xs:element name="Ipadress">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the pattern value to "\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d{1,3}"